# How to rebind the copy/paste shortcut keys?

Tags: release-loki, settings, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am an emacs user, and the elementaryOS short-cut keys for copy/paste really bug me. Is it possible to rebind C-c, C-v, C-a to super-c, super-v, super-a etc? (where super is the cmd/win key - i use a macbookpro) ?

Or any other way to rebind the copy/paste shortcut keys?

thanks

Comment: The GTK based applications should unify their shortcuts, such as using Super key based bindings for all shortcuts to provide a consistent experience. Such experience is implemented under macOS.
Ctrl based shortcuts need to move hands away from the center of the keyboard, it is hard to say that's shortcut.